# What is the best way to express a query for a = b = c?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three tables (t1, t2, t3) and they are exact copies of each other.  Each table has columns a, b, c that are random integers.

I want to query t1.a = t2.b = t3.c.

However, if I query t1.a = t2.b = t3.c, I am getting false results.  It looks like every single row is being joined.  Why is this?

If I query t1.a = t2.b and t2.b = t3.c, my query returns good results.

Should I specify t1.a = t2.b and t2.b = t3.c and t1.a = t3.c?

What is the best way to logically express t1.a = t2.b = t3.c?

Comment: `Should I specify t1.a = t2.b and t2.b = t3.c and t1.a = t3.c?` - yes.

Comment: please show use your real query

Comment: N.B. I would expect `a = b = c` to be evaluated as `a = (b = c)` which is equivalent to the expression `(b = c AND a = 1) OR (b != c AND a = 0)`.  This is not as illogical as it might seem, because `TRUE` = numeric 1, `FALSE` = numeric 0, and the value of `a` is being compared to the boolean result of evaluating `b = c`, which would always be one of { 0, 1, NULL } and this explains the apparently incorrect rresults.

Comment: Explain your intentions clearly (in steps) in the POST so that you might get more help/attention! (if below answers do not satisfy you)

Answer (score 1):

For the filter condition **a = b = c** specify

```
 t1.a = t2.b and t2.b = t3.c
```

It should be enough to serve the purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, as this will filter the results step by step:

- `table1` and `table2` (lets say this result `filteredResult1`)
- `filteredResult1` and `table3` (lets sat it `filteredFinalResult`)

---

**filteredFinalResult** can be fetched using:

```
SELECT 
    t1.*, t2.*, t3.* 
FROM 
    table1 t1 
INNER JOIN 
    table2 t2 
ON 
    t1.a = t2.b 
INNER JOIN 
    table3 t3 
ON 
    t2.b = t3.c
```